# copy installed programs and settings to new user

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts, administrator

I just installed Windows 8.1 and it seems like the user I created is corrupt. I was advised to create a new Administrator Account.

This seems like it solved the particular issue I was having, but now I see I have none of my documents, settings and more importantly - programs/applications that took me a few hours to install on the previous account, simply do not exist on the new one.

Is there really no way to easily share programs between users on the same PC? 
Please tell me there is a work-around...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there really no way to easily share programs between users on the same PC?

Depends on the program as to whether it is single or multi-user accessible after install.  If you're talking about Windows 8 Store Apps, then they are definitely per-user.

> I see I have none of my documents

All your documents should still be in your old user's profile folder (usually in `c:\users`); that is unless it was corrupted bad enough, in which case they're probably gone for good.

Keep in mind that users' documents (and even programs) are separated on purpose, for security reasons.

For future reference/ease: make regular backups.

Comment: Thanks. Yes - my documents are in the other user file. and no - I didnt meant Store Apps - i meant programs, like MS Office, Adobe programs etc.  
So is there a way to share them or move them over? or do they need to be re-installed?